# Change the text color inside a gridview in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am using a gridview inside a listview.My grid view has two colums ID and Result.I am loading the gridview from a List.So result column has two types of values positive and negative.I want to display text color green for **positive** and red for **negative** and also attach an icon alongside the textblock.

Is it possible in xaml ? Or  am i trying to implement which is not possible ?

How to bind the color based on the values coming from the list into the grid ?

```
 <ListView Height="166" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,0,0,0" Name="lvStatus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Result">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Result}"/>
                                    <Image  ></Image>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ae4cd800-3572-47ee-a850-abd55c83c41f

Comment: Please provide XAML you are using so it would be much easier to give you working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Converter` that returns `Green` if the specified value is above 0, and `Red` if it is below 0, and use it to determine the Foreground color of your Text

```
public class NumberToColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return (((double)value) > 0 ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red);
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid Value");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can then use your converter like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NumberToColorBrushConverter x:Key="NumberToColorBrushConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}" Foreground={Binding Result, 
    Converter={StaticResource NumberToColorBrushConverter}}" />
```

**Edit**

If you have a value in your data which determines Positive or Negative, then you don't even need to use a Converter. Here's an example that uses a DataTrigger

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ResultTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositiveOrNegative}" Value="Negative">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}" Style="{StaticResource ResultTextBlockStyle}" />
```

Comment: Rachel:How do i intrepet the value which i get from the list..say supppose i have the string in the list with value "Positive" then i want to display green color for the text ?

Comment: @Macnique That is much easier because you don't need to use a Converter. I updated my answer with an example for that.

Comment: @ Rachel It works absolutely fine.Is it possible to bind a check mark icon or uncheck icon beside the textblock

Comment: @Macnique Yes, just wrap your `TextBlock` in some other panel (such as a Horizontal `StackPanel`) along with an Image for your icon. You can also base your Image's Source off a DataTrigger or a Converter if you want